# How to assign all properties of a parameter that satisfies an interface to a class that implements the interface in Typescript?

Tags: typescript, class, types

I have `interface CommunityProps` and `class Community implements CommunityProps`. I would like to do something like this:

```js
class Community implements CommunityProps {
   // property declarations
   constructor(props: CommunityProps) {
      Object.assign(this, props)
   }
}
```

But Object.assign is not typesafe. I am stuck listing out all 10-15 properties in 1) the interface, 2) the class property declarations, and 3) one-by-one assigning the class properties to `props.propName` where `props` is passed into the constructor, like this:

```js
interface CommunityProps {
   prop1: string
   prop2: number
   prop3: boolean
}
class Community implements CommunityProps {
   prop1: string
   prop2: number
   prop3: boolean
   constructor(props: CommunityProps) {
      this.prop1 = props.prop1
      this.prop2 = props.prop2
      this.prop3 = props.prop3
   }
}
```

I have about 10 such classes I need to make, each with a different set of properties. This will leave me with about 450 lines of code just to get these classes working. Surely there is a better way to do what I am trying to do?

The best alternative I have found is giving the class a single property which is of the same type as the interface, and remove the `implements CommunityProps` from the class declaration:

```js
class Community {
   info: CommunityProps
   constructor(props: CommunityProps) {
      this.info = props
   }
}
```

But I would really, really like to be able to access these properties without having to use `.info.prop1`

Comment: You can confine the type safety hole to a single class factory function and use it 10 times, like [this](https://tsplay.dev/w652GW) for `Community`.  See the linked question/answer.